# Embedding variable length "multi-hot-encoded" features

Tags: keras, embeddings

How can I implement an embedding layer in Keras that takes in an input that could have a variable length? For instance, if the vocabulary was 10-long I could have inputs like:

```
[1]
[2,4,5]
[7,3]
```

But Keras embedding does not accept variable length inputs. I guess it is possible for me to zero-pad so that it looks like:

```
[1,0,0]
[2,4,5]
[7,3,0]
```

But this would make some of the inputs quite long (in my particular case, up to length ~500 vectors in a vocab of maybe ~10000). If only one data example has length 500 it forces even ones of length 1 to be zero padded to 500.

Is there a better way to handle variable length inputs?